Not able to make an object of a class in a different class
I'm trying to create an object of a different class to be used in the present class, but unable to do so. Here is an instance of the code I'm trying to implement:
class Party : public Server, public Client
{
    net::io_context& ioc_;
    net::ip::address address_;
    int port;
    Server party_server;
    Client party_client;

    public:
        Party(net::io_context& ioc, const std::string& address, int port) : ioc_(ioc), address_(net::ip::make_address(address)),
            port(port), party_server(ioc,address,port), party_client(ioc) {}
        
        
};

I'm continuously getting this error:

no default constructor exists for class "Server" C/C++(291)

I tried to implement using nested classes (without inheritance), but it didn't help. Also, I tried keeping two different constructors for the class 'server' and class 'client', and that didn't work either.

Why do you both inherit from Server, Client and have members of these types ?

Either Server needs to have a default constructor (i.e. with no parameters), or it must be initialized in the member initializer list.

The problem is that you inherit from Server, but you do not initialize the parent Server class in your initializer list with suitable arguments.

Dupes: Class member without a default constructor and No default constructor exists for class error

That's because I need to use the functions declared in these classes in the 'Party' class

All in all, it seem you kind of misunderstand the usage of inheritance and composition. As @wohlstad wonders, why do you use both?

@ShreyasShivapuji you can use the Server and Client methods via the members party_server, party_client (using data members like that is a part the "composition" concept). Inheritance is an alternative to composition.

@Someprogrammerdude as you said, I might've been confused with the usage of inheritance. What could be the possible solution to this then?

@user12002570 the OP seems to have some misunderstanding about the issue of composition v.s. inheritance. I don't think the dupes will help them.

@shreyas this post offers some insights on the issue of composition v.s. inheritance.

Inheritance is an is-a relationship. Is Party both a Server and a Client? If not then it should not inherit from those classes. Does a Party have a Server and/or a Client? Then it should contain members of those classes (composition).

@wohlstad That doesn't change the actual problem which is that they don't have a default ctor for their class. Also I've added another dupe Prefer composition over inheritance? and Inheritance or composition: Rely on "is-a" and "has-a"?

Now I got the point, I need to use composition here instead of inheritance. Thanks @wohlstad and Some programmer dude. But still how can I resolve the error of default ctor? Is there any error in the declaration I've made in the class 'Party'

If you remove the inheritance the problem should be solved (at least that's my guess).

@user12002570 the last dupe in the list is indeed more helpful and relevant.

@wohlstad Yeah, though all of the targets should give OP some idea about what they're missing.
